# Supposed to get the child but somehow gets the parent ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, children

Good day. I have a code. To my understanding, the clicked2 should get the id "Third" since it's looking for the children. But somehow, it always get the id "First". How do i get the "Third"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div class="menu" id="First">
       <button id="Second">eee</button>
       <button id="Third">yyy</button>
    </div>
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).on('click', '.menu', function(e) {
               var clicked = e.target.id || this.id;
               var clicked2 = e.target.children.id || this.id;
               var y = clicked2.replace(/\D/g, '');
               var x = clicked.replace(/\D/g, '');
               var w = 0;

               $('.holder') .append('<BR>'+clicked+'<BR>'+clicked2);

               });

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First problem: `e.target.children.id` will always be undefined as _element_.children is a HTMLCollection, so does not have an ID - so, clicked2 can only ever be `this.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `var clicked2 = $(this).children("button").next().attr("id")`
 It will return id of the second button.

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu', function(e) {
var clicked = e.target.id || this.id;
var clicked2 = $(this).children("button").next().attr("id") || this.id;


var y = clicked2.replace(/\D/g, '');
var x = clicked.replace(/\D/g, '');
var w = 0;

$('.holder') .append('<BR>'+clicked+'<BR>'+clicked2);

   });
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/d0yrjz78/)**

Answer (score 0):

[children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) returns all the childrens, so you need to adress the right one:

```
var clicked2 = $(this).children().next().attr("id");
```